# How to implement Dynamic columns from Mariadb in Oracle?

Tags: oracle

I have a MariaDB database which uses [dynamic columns](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/dynamic-columns/).

There are around 10 such columns, because the data comes from many different devices and each of the device has different attributes. The devices send some binary data which is converted into csv and then inserted. I don't have control over this at all.

Now I am planning to migrate to oracle database 12.2 but not sure how to migrate the dynamic columns to Oracle. Any ideas please?

Comment: Is this for JSON? i.e. Why are you using this feature? (& what is the predominant data style being stored this way?) How many tables are affected? How varied are the column sets in each table?

Comment: Around 10 of them approximately this is because the data comes from many different devices and each of the device has different attributes

Comment: So it's device logging data? What is the native format of the source data JSON? XML? CSV?

Comment: The device/devices sends some binary data which is then converted into csv and then inserted and i don't have control over this at all.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle RDBMS doesn't support this feature natively, so you will have to write some procedures to implement something analogous to the MariaDB calls.

The closest functionality to dynamic columns is JSON. You're moving to Oracle 12.2 which has pretty JSON support. [Find out more](https://docs.oracle.com/database/122/ADJSN/intro-to-json-data-and-oracle-database.htm#ADJSN-GUID-17642E43-7D87-4590-8870-06E9FDE9A6E9). Unless your data is very complicated with lots of nesting it should be trivial to turn CSV into JSON. Once you have JSON is easy to insert, maintain and retrieve the data using Oracle's functionality.